# How do I become a zombie?

Tags: realm-of-the-mad-god

After a long hiatus, I've picked up RotMG again and noticed a few stark changes.

Quite often it'll say

`<Name>'s cursed amulet of resurrection has broken and they (become a zombie|disappear|something similar)`

This prompts the most dismay and pity I think I've ever seen in an MMO. :P  Particularly when the affected turns into a zombie, it seems.  ("Poor `<Name>`.  Zombied right at the end.")

The [Wiki](https://forums.wildshadow.com/wiki/realm-mad-god) seems to contain little to nothing on the topic.

What's an amulet of resurrection and what does it do?  Are some *un*-cursed?  How can I get one?  What happens when it breaks and you turn into a zombie?

Comment: Check the wiki again, they have updated info:  https://forums.wildshadow.com/wiki/realm-mad-god/cursed-amulet-resurrection

Comment: @HenryHey Looks to me like the beginnings of an answer... :D

Answer (score 2):

The Cursed Amulets of Resurrection have been changed to Cursed Amulets of Zombification.  If you're wearing one when you're killed you'll become a zombie.

From the [wiki description](http://www.realmeye.com/wiki/cursed-amulet-of-zombification):

> As of build 4.0.0, Amulet of Resurrection’s name was changed to Cursed
>   Amulet of Resurrection. It became soulbound and you could buy it in
>   Nexus for 1,000 fame, but there was a 5-10% chance that it would not
>   work and you would be “zombified” (killing your character). It was
>   rumored everytime a player died with an ammy, the chance to be
>   zombified grew by 0.01, and that after 10,000 ammy breaks there would
>   be a 100% zombification chance.
>
> As of build 4.3.0, The Cursed Amulet’s chance to help you cheat death
>   was evidently decreased, rough estimates suggest a resurrection chance
>   of below 40%.
>
> As of build 5.0.0, Cursed Amulets had a 100% zombification chance and
>   dropped from the boss in the dungeon “Haunted Cemetery.”